# Debugging Linux program which crashes before main

Tags: linux, gdb, disassembly, objdump

The program crashes before main. Heres the gdb output

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff3732abb in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&) () from /opt/example/libstdc++.so.6
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install LynxService-0.10-10.x86_64 LynxService-0.6-6.x86_64 glibc-2.17-55.el7.x86_64 keyutils-libs-1.5.8-3.el7.x86_64 krb5-libs-1.11.3-49.el7.x86_64 libcom_err-1.42.9-4.el7.x86_64 libselinux-2.2.2-6.el7.x86_64 pcre-8.32-12.el7.x86_64 xz-libs-5.1.2-8alpha.el7.x86_64 zlib-1.2.7-13.el7.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff3732abb in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&) () from /opt/example/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff4214f15 in ?? () from /opt/example/libNetwork.so
#2  0x00007ffff4215ef4 in ?? () from /opt/example/libNetwork.so
#3  0x00007ffff7deb503 in ?? () from /opt/example/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#4  0x00007ffff7ddd45a in ?? () from /opt/example/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#5  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#6  0x00007fffffffe139 in ?? ()
#7  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

On multiple instance of gdb invocation the address of the stack frames (i.e 0x00007ffff4215ef4) remains same.

The output of ** objdump -TC libNetwork.so** does not contain text 0x00007ffff4215ef4.

The program has linked to many dependencies and it is very hard to remove the library linking one by one and test it.

Since the stack frame address is same always, it looks like this should be debuggable, but does not know how.

Comment: Looks like your `libNetwork` have constructors. Can you link minimal program with it and run it? Or even `LD_PRELOAD=/opt/example/libNetwork.so /bin/true`, and see if it would crash.

Comment: Thanks. The older version of library was present at location /opt/example/libNetwork.so. Replacing it with newly compiled library solved the issue